# Making a flat file from vector array

Tags: c++, flat

My plan is to make a flat file  in two columns and for that this is what I have initiated two vector arrays. Two vector arrays will be in two column of the flat file. I think the problem I'm having is to fill the vector elements in the columns of flat file. Am I filling in wrong way?

`outFile << vec1[i] << "\t" << vec2[i] << endl;`

```
  #include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
//int main()
void ffile()
{
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("flatFile.dat");
     vector<int> vec1{ 10, 20 };
     vector<int> vec2{ 0, 20, 30 };


    for (int i=0; i<=3;i++)

{
  outFile << vec1[i] << "\t" << vec2[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Updated question: 
I have two vector with different vector size. Will it any problem if I use the size the large vector  running the code?

Another thing is that, in the flat file I do not see two column, instead I see only one column and the entries coming from the vector vec2[i] . How to have both entries  in the first column for the vec1, and for the second column for the vec2?

Comment: A first issue: `i<5` Use `vec1.size()` instead

Comment: Your `for` loop iterates 5 times but your vectors only contain 3 elements. So when `i` >=3, boom!

Comment: Your (commented) output looks OK but: How do want to output 5 values if `vec1` and `vec2` contain only 3?

Comment: thanks, updated accordingly. And updated the question.

Comment: Your program will crash if you iterate to the size of the larger array.

Comment: Note: if you want a good formating and if integers can have quite different values, using tab `\t` may not be enough. Look at `std::setw`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not allow to read from a vector past its last element. Full stop. If you use the `at` method, you will get an `out_of_range` exception, and with the `[]` operator you just experience undefined behaviour.

That means that you will have to check the size of the vector. You code could become:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
//int main()
void ffile()
{
    // std::ofstream ofs;     // unused 
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("flatFile.dat");
    vector<int> vec1{ 10, 20 };
    vector<int> vec2{ 0, 20, 30 };

    // use the sizes of both vectors to compute the loop limit
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= std::max(vec1.size(), vec2.size()); i++)

    {
        if (i < vec1.size()) outFile << vec1[i];  // only output actual values
        outFile << "\t";
        if (i < vec2.size()) outFile << vec2[i];
        outFile << endl;
    }
}
```

This code should give a text file similar to:

```
0   0
20  20
    30
```

(it did in my tests...)

Comment: `ofs` is unused

Comment: @acraig5075: you are right. I forgot to comment it in my code. It is now. Thanks for noticing.